# I want to merge two rows like if first row x x x x a x x and second row x x x x x b x then result should be x x x x a b x

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel with list of data separated of material move from one location to another location. Each row contains either "from" location or "to" location including quantity where all other information such as date, product, document_no are same. Each valid transaction has two rows (example: moving 1 qty of product A to Y from X,then one row with "from location" as X in -1 quantity and another row as "to location" Y and quantity 1). I would like to merge the two rows of "from" and "to" location into one row where "from" and "to" are different columns.

I tried to search and find options...

[image: Check the picture please]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How have you tried to solve this?  This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. It might be helpful for you to read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then edit your original question to show where you have run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

So, not sure how you want this laid out as you don't provide any example, but here is an option you can edit to suit:

[image]

Comment: @MohammedNisar You should edit your original question with the information you show in your comment. That changes the question so I will let you work out how to edit what I provided as an answer to suit your needs.

Comment: i dont have the option to edit the original question.

Comment: @MohammedNisar Yes you do, you wrote it you can edit it. I can still edit the few questions I wrote... click on the word "edit" at the bottom. Pity you removed that comment with all the real info though... without any effort you won't get more of a solution.

Comment: sorry for that, i thought the copy paste from excel will work but here in comment box it ddnt work. I edited the question and hop that it more clear with picture.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by making a pivot table.